# Windows Workflow Foundation persistence schema explanation?

Tags: .net, sql, workflow, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to debug a workflow project that's using the default WF SQL persistence schema.  Does anyone know of a good explanation for what the data in each table represents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only two tables in the persistence schema are the InstanceState and CompletedScope tables. The InstanceState table stores the where/when/who of what is happening with the workflow at the point it was unloaded. The CompletedScope table stores completed workflows that are compensatable I believe.

If you want to know more about the tracking tables as well, here's a good link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347864.aspx